# How to prove the accuracy of this equation?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

How to prove the accuracy of this equation?

$$(\sinh x + \cosh x)^{n} = \sinh nx + \cosh nx$$

I already know:

$$\sinh x= \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}$$
And
$$\cosh x= \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}$$
But I failed to prove it, since I don't see any point to start from.

Comment: Use the two defitions you know and substitute them into the LHS and RHS of your equation.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font ans spacing.  So \sinh x gives $\sinh x$ instead of sinh x giving $sinh x$

Comment: Why use the `triangles` tag?

Comment: Just simplify $\sinh x+\cosh x$ first

Comment: @DavidQuinn it becomes $e^{x}$!

Comment: So there you go…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hints of Blitzer and David Quinn found a way.

Simplified LHS:
$$({\frac{e^{x} - e^{-x} + e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}})^{n} = $$
$$(\frac{2e^{x}}{2})^{n} = e^{nx}$$

Simplified RHS:
$${\frac{e^{nx} - e^{-nx} + e^{nx} + e^{-nx}}{2}} = $$
$$\frac{2e^{nx}}{2} = e^{nx}$$

LHS = RHS, so proved.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sinh (x) + \cosh (x))^{n} = \sinh (nx) + \cosh (nx)$$ Let $x=i\,y$ to make
$$(\cos (y)+i \sin (y))^n=\cos (n y)+i \sin (n y)$$